# Несколько таблиц для одной модели Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Есть ли возможность в Django реализовать несколько таблиц для одной модели?

Требуется создать систему, где есть модель1, модель2, модель3 и т.д. и пользователи, для которых данные в БД не пересекаются. Хотелось бы не хранить информацию о пользователе в этих моделях, а при добавлении пользователя создавать для него отдельные таблицы. Пользователей будет около 100.

Comment: Ужасное архитектурное решение. Правильно было бы как раз хранить информацию о пользователе в модели.

Comment: Вряд ли в этом есть какой-то смысл